# Does this seem like an accurate translation?

Tags: meaning, translation, word-choice

Sorry if this is the wrong place to post this, I'm trying to translate a short comic that's only in Japanese, and wanted to check whether or not I'm doing alright

1: 夢野ちゃんはさ

1: いつまで魔法使いでいるのか？

2: なあ?

2: なんじゃ急に

1: いや、ごめんごめん

1: 別に今聞 くことじゃなかったよねー

1: Hey Yumeno-Chan!

1: How long do you intend to be a witch?/How long do you plan on being a mage/witch?

2: Nyeh?

2: Why are you asking all of a sudden?

1: No, sorry, sorry/Ah, sorry, sorry

1: Well it's not like we have to discuss this now/We don't exactly have to discuss it today/Well it's not like I have to hear about it now/Weell it's nothing I have to hear about now, right?

Also since I may as well ask, the next line is from 1 saying "忘れてくれる?", which a few places claim would translate to "Just forget about it" or "Forget about it", but I didn't think that made sense when there's a question mark at the end. Would "Don't want me to say it?" Or "Want to forget about it?" seem more accurate?

♧ ——————————————————————— ♧

Edit before I've even posted:

They're close I think, also since 1 added くれる on the end, would it be more like "Want to forget about giving me an answer?" So does 2 want 1 to forget about receiving one?[image]

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to the Japanese language stack exchange. Questions asking for proof-reading are typically considered off-topic (see the guidelines here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), although we welcome more specific questions. That said, for what it's worth, I would broadly characterize your translation as "roughly accurate but slightly off in tone/detail in a few places".

Comment: Can you paste the original manga as an image if you can? I feel there's a confusion regarding who said what. (I doubt this `なあ?` is something said by the speaker 2.)

Comment: Thank you! Ah yeah I wasn't sure sorry, I'll look through everything in the links you've sent me!

Comment: Also Naruto, I posted it. She says that a lot outside of this fan manga in game, the localisation team translated it as 'Nyeh' a lot for some reason so I guess I was just following along. Uhm I'll try not to be such a noob poster next time

Comment: @Veex To ensure that your comments reach the person you talking to you should put an '@' in front of their user name.

Comment: Ah, it was "んあ?", not "なあ?"

Comment: Oh, uhm thank you! Sorry, @naruto Ah I didn't even notice that if that changes things, yeah

Answer (score 0):

This looks good to me, although I've never heard of "nyeh" and might consider something more usual ("huh" or something). なあ？ sounds weird to me, I'm not sure if this is supposed to be angry or stammering of 何.

As for 忘れてくれる？, this could be translated as "would you be so kind as to forget about it?," although that's much too polite. More polite than 忘れてくれ, which would be "forget it." So yeah, it's basically the same thing as "just forget it" or "would you drop it?" or something of the like. The fact that it's a question isn't important and doesn't need to be translated.

Answer (score 0):

Your translation seems good overall. The first word from 2 is んあ, which is something like "Huh?", "Hmm?" or "Um?". なあ doesn't have such a meaning. I don't know how "Nyeh" works in that manga.

"忘れてくれる?" is technically a question, "Will you forget (for me)?", but "Forget about it" is perfectly fine, too. (You are comfortable with donatory verbs like くれる/もらう, right?) So 1 wants 2 to forget about the silly question on this page.